# Styled Components hiding HTML attributes in Typescript

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I create a standard Styled Component like:

```
export type ContainerProps = {
  color: string;
};

export const Container = styled.div<ContainerProps>`
  color: ${p => p.color};
  background: blue;
  width: 100%
`;
```

When I want to use this component in JSX  I have all the HTML attributes available as props.

Is there any way how to restrict these, so that the user can use only props specified in props type?

Comment: Would a wrapper work? `const ContainerDiv = styled.div/*...*/; export const Component = (props: ContainerProps) => <ContainerDiv {...props} />;` (I don't use `styled-components`, so...) (Add `children?: ReactNode` to `ContainerProps` if you want to allow it to have children.)

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible example with all imports and commented error ?

Comment: (Gah. I meant `export const Container =`, not `export const Component =`.)

Comment: Wrapping components is something I want to avoid, no Wrapper is better for me now than having restricted Components, I am looking for a way to tell SC to construct component type from my props only.

Comment: @Jarek - I'm afraid I don't understand the question. You've said *"...When I want to use this component in JSX I have all the HTML attributes available as props..."* but you've then said *"...Is there any way how to restrict these, so that the user can use only access props specified in props type?..."* Can you clarify that? Do you want all of the HTML attributes, or just what's specified in the props type?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I want only properties in prop type, I want to prevent user to modify anything that is not specified as prop, and without wrapper. Answer from Rahul provides reasonable solution, there is little price to pay, in specifying extra type, which is not nicest thing to do, but acceptable in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to achieve it, check the implementation [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/main/packages/styled-components/src/constructors/styled.tsx)

A naive approach can be, to create another component and export this.

```
export const StyledContainer = styled.div<ContainerProps>`
  color: ${(p) => p.color};
  background: blue;
  width: 100%
`;

export const Container: FC<ContainerProps> = (...props) => (
  <StyledContainer {...props} />
);
```

**SC adds extra default HTML props(onClick, onBlur etc), If we provide FC it'll only accept Type props.**

```
export type ContainerProps = {
  color: string,
};
export const Container: FC<ContainerProps> = styled.div<ContainerProps>`
  color: ${(p) => p.color};
  background: blue;
  width: 100%
`;
```

Comment: Perhaps explain why a wrapper component is "naive," what the "hacky solution" does, and why you think it's hacky?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think I should say type conversion, not hack.

Comment: What type conversion? I don't see any...?

Comment: SC adds extra props(onClick, onBlur etc) right, If we provide FC<Type> it'll only accept Type props right. We are bonding(converting ) to another type.